# determinant of integrals of forms

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, differential-topology, differentials

Let $A$ be a complex abelian variety of dimension $d$. Let $\omega_1, \ldots, \omega_j \in H^0(A, \Omega^1_A)$ be linearly independent (so $j \leq d$) and consider $\gamma_1, \ldots, \gamma_j \in H_1(A(\mathbb{C}), \mathbb{Q})$. Look at the matrix

$M=(\int_{\gamma_i} \omega_j)$

Is it possible to express the determinant of $M$ as the integral of $\omega_1 \wedge \ldots \wedge \omega_j \in H^0(A, \Omega^j_A)$ against some element of $H_j(A(\mathbb{C}), \mathbb{Q})$ constructed out of $\gamma_1, \ldots, \gamma_j$?

Comment: What if the dimension of $X$ is less than $n$?  Do you want to assume that $X$ is a complex torus and $\omega_1,\dots,\omega_n$ form a basis?

Comment: In that case both sides are zero, no? But you are right that the case I have in mind is $X$ an abelian variety of dimension $n$ and $\omega_i$ a basis of $H^0(X, \Omega^1_X)$

Comment: "In that case both sides are zero, no?"  Why?  Certainly the integral you write is zero, but that does not imply that the determinant is zero.  That is why I raised my objection.

Comment: What is $\gamma _1\cup\ldots \cup \gamma _n$?

Comment: The cup product

Comment: Thanks Jason. Ok, let me ask this question: you take an abelian variety of dimension $d$, a basis of $H^0(A, \Omega^1_A)$, you pick some cycles $\gamma_1, \ldots, \gamma_d$ and you write the corresponding matrix. Is it possible to express its determinant as the integral of $\omega_1 \wedge \cdots \wedge \omega_d$ (now an element of $H^0(A, \Omega^d)$) over a suitable cycle in $H_d(A(\mathbb{C}), \mathbb{Q})$?

Comment: You can't take the cup-product of homology classes! Cup-product is an operation on cohomology, so the cycle you're integrating over is nonsensical as soon as $n > 1$.

Comment: Umm, good point. What is then the operation dual to cup-product?

Comment: I edited the question

Answer (score 1):

You can form the $j$-fold self product, $A^j$, together with its addition morphism to $A$, $$\Sigma:A^j \to A.$$  Via Künneth, you have an inclusion $$\bigotimes_{i=1}^j H_1(A;\mathbb{Q}) \hookrightarrow H_j(A^j;\mathbb{Q}).$$  Now take the image of the cycle $\gamma_1\otimes \dots \otimes \gamma_j$ in $H_j(A^j;\mathbb{Q})$, and then take the pushforward via the morphism $\Sigma$ (proper and locally a fiber bundle) to get a class $\gamma\in H_j(A;\mathbb{Q})$.  Similarly, given de Rham differentials, $$\omega_1,\dots,\omega_j \in H^{1,0}(A),$$
you can form $\omega= \omega_1\wedge \dots \wedge \omega_j$.  Consider $\int_\gamma \omega$, or equivalently, the pairing, $$\int_\gamma \omega = \langle \Sigma^*(\omega_1\wedge \dots \wedge \omega_j),\gamma_1\otimes \dots \otimes \gamma_j\rangle.$$
Then you can ask whether or not, $$ \int_\gamma \omega = \text{det}\left[\int_{\gamma_\alpha} \omega_\beta\right]_{1\leq \alpha,\beta \leq j}?$$

Of course, ultimately, this has nothing to do with the differentials $\omega_\beta$ being contained in $H^{1,0}(A)$.  Really this is a question about the singular cohomology of $A$: how does the Hopf algebra structure induced by addition behave?  That question answers itself: the cohomology is a **Hopf algebra**.  More precisely, it is the free exterior algebra on $H^1(A;\mathbb{Q})$ (with the usual trace on the top exterior power) equipped with its standard structure of cocommutative Hopf algebra.  In particular, considered as an element in $H^1(A;\mathbb{Q})\otimes H^1(A;\mathbb{Q})$, $\Delta(\omega_\beta)$ equals $\omega_\beta\otimes 1 + 1\otimes \omega_\beta$, where $\Delta$ is pullback via addition, $$m:A\times A \to A,$$ together with the Künneth isomorphism, $$H^1(A\times A;\mathbb{Q}) = \left(H^1(A;\mathbb{Q})\otimes \mathbb{Q}\right) \oplus \left(\mathbb{Q}\otimes H^1(A;\mathbb{Q}) \right).$$  By my computation, this does imply that the Künneth component in $H^1(A;\mathbb{Q})\otimes \dots \otimes H^1(A;\mathbb{Q})$
of $\Sigma^*(\omega_1\wedge \dots \wedge \omega_j)$ is equal to $$\sum_{\sigma\in{\mathfrak{S}_j}} \text{sgn}(\sigma) \omega_{\sigma(1)}\otimes \dots \otimes \omega_{\sigma(j)}$$ (it would be wise for you to double-check that computation).  Thus the pairing against $\gamma_1\otimes \dots \otimes \gamma_j$ equals $$\int_\gamma \omega =    \sum_{\sigma\in{\mathfrak{S}_j}} \text{sgn}(\sigma) \langle \omega_{\sigma(1)}\otimes \dots \otimes \omega_{\sigma(j)}, \gamma_1\otimes \dots \otimes\gamma_j \rangle = \text{det}\left[\int_{\gamma_\alpha} \omega_\beta\right]_{1\leq \alpha,\beta \leq j}.$$